# Spring Integration @Transactional rollback of many database operations

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rollback, transactional

My problem is simple, **I want to rollback all the db changes that were caused by invocation of my service method.** I have a problem with correct annotating. I'm not really sure where to put `@Transactional` and where should I set Propagation to `REQUIRES_NEW` or `MANDATORY`. I will paste a code that I wrote, which apart from the fact that `SQLException` is thrown *does not rollback db changes*.

The code:

```
@Service
public class SwapInsertService {

    @Autowired
    MyDao myDao;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQURIES_NEW, rollbackFor = SQLException.class)
    public void insertToManyTables(MyData data) throws SQLException {

        insertToSpecificTables(data);
        myDao.insertTwo(data);
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
    public void insertToSpecificTables(MyData data) throws SQLException {

        myDao.insertOne(data);
    }
}

@Repository
public class MyDaoImpl implements MyDao {

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
    public void insertOne(MyData data) throws SQLException {

        // INSERT
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
    public void insertTwo(MyData data) throws SQLException {

        // throws SQLException 
    }
}
```

Let's assume `insertTwo` throws `SQLException` . I would like to rollback all the previous inserts. **What am I doing wrong?**

**My understanding:**

`Propagation.REQURIES_NEW` creates new transaction. 
`Propagation.MANDATORY` supports current transaction.

`insertTwo` throws error, `insertToManyTables` rollbacks everything and voilà. Unfortunately it is not that easy.

**EDIT**: It's important to mention that i'm using `CGLIB` for proxies.

Comment: Did you declare the TransactionManager (`<bean id="txManager"...`) correctly in the spring config? see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html#transaction-declarative

Comment: Yes, it's declared and I see in logs that there are proxies created. As far as I know proxies creation is fired by @Transactional. I'm using CGLIB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check whether AUTO_COMMIT is set to false in data source configuration in spring specific xml

Comment: I'll take a look and let you know. I did't consider this. Thx.

Comment: It looks like you were right, my data source was set to auto commit. Thx.